# dynamic way to display locally had PDF's in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

I apologize in advance if this is seemingly too simple of a question, however I'm confusing myself and would like a little help.

Basically at this point I have a script included on my site that goes:

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function embedPDF(){
            var success = new PDFObject({
         url: 'Vol_1.4.pdf','0' }
        }).embed("pdfRenderer");
    }   
 window.onload = embedPDF;
```

this is great for displaying one PDF, however I would like to have a page with links to many other PDFs as well. So what I would ideally like to be able to do is put that script in a method that goes:

```
def idealMethod(urlName)
//Here is the previously mentioned script
end
```

so that on my page linking to all the locally held pdfs, I could just do something like a link to a generic page

```
<%= link_to "Volume 1", pdf_path, :id => "links" %>
```

wherein the aforementioned method would take in the "Volume 1" title and run the script to open the correct Volume 1.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing javascript code and rails code.  The easiest way to do what you want is to observe the links and not a ruby method which you plan to reuse.

First, use class instead of id for the links

```
<%= link_to "Volume 1", pdf_path, class: 'pdf-link' %>
```

Then add the following js code

```
function embedPDF(url){
  new PDFObject({ url: url }).embed("pdfRenderer")
}   

$('.pdf-link').on('click', function() { embedPDF(this.href) })
```